# Using a windows batch to remote connect to Linux via OpenSSH

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file, ssh, openssh

I want to remote connect to a Linux machine using OpenSSH in a windows batch.

When I enter

```
>ssh <ip address>
```

I am prompted for the password of the remote machine

```
>password:
```

which is very cumbersome to react to in a windows batch, that has to run automatically.

How can I connect to a Linux machine using OpenSSH without being prompted for the password? Is there a way to include the pw in the ssh command? Or any other good solutions (other than removing the pw from the Linux machine)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Xshell` and make settings that cater to your request...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you expand on this a little and give a concrete example? I have never worked with Xshell.

Comment: **Xshell** is a powerful SSH, TELNET and RLOGIN terminal emulator software operating on the 
Windows platform. Windows users can conveniently and securely access UNIX/Linux hosts using 
**Xshell**. SSH (secure shell) protocols support encryption and user authentication for secure 
connection on the Internet and can replace legacy protocols, such as TELNET and RLOGIN. 

Here is a vivid guide for you to get started https://www.netsarang.com/tutorial/xshell/2776/Getting_Started